# Django Rest API foreign key serializers error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Trying to serialize my models. I want the end-point should display data with its related data (foregin key).

but i got an error and that is

```
TypeError: 'Author' object is not iterable
```

These are my serializer classes

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Author, Article, Category


class AuthorSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'

class CategorySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

and these are my models

```
   from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and these are my views:

```
class ArticleListCreateGet(ListAPIView, CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

class ArticleSingle(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'


# This is delete/update method
class ArticleDeleteUpdate(DestroyAPIView, UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pk'
```

and these are my url

```
path('api/v1/article', views.ArticleListCreateGet.as_view(), name='article'),
    path('api/v1/article/<int:pk>/detail', views.ArticleSingle.as_view(), name='article-single'),
    path('api/v1/article/<int:pk>', views.ArticleDeleteUpdate.as_view(), name='article-delete-update'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `Article` has *foreign key* to `Author` and `Category`. So each article has only one author or category and you don't need to set `many=True` in `ArticleSerializer`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Article

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    category = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = '__all__'
```